# How to take aws credentials from aws-vault exec

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vault

I want to take aws credentials from the aws-vault exec environment and store them in a file

When I try to print the credentials with
`aws-vault exec default -- echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}` I got only an empty string

Comment: Did you try: `aws-vault exec default -- env | grep AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [aws-vault : How it works](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault#how-it-works),

**Environment variables** (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` etc.) are written to the sub-process with `aws-vault exec`, so you can grep out for `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` like below:-

```bash
aws-vault exec default -- env | grep AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

Comment: This should also work:- `aws-vault exec default -- env | echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`